# Bitcoin to XRP wallet transaction lost

Tags: ripple, coinbase.com

I use Coinbase.  Went to to purchase XRP so created a toast wallet.  I then sent the btc to xrp wallet via Coinbase.  The transaction showed complete a few hours later but never showed up in my xrp toast wallet.  I checked the address sent to, for some reason is different than my current xrp wallet address and therefore the wallet never got activated.  I checked the block for the address it got sent to and it seems that transactions is long gone in the past with activity sold two days after I sent to my xrp wallet.  Upon research, I found somewhere that I should have sent the btc to the wallet first (which i thought it was) and then to xrp, instead it goes to a coinbase hot wallet?? And to contact Coinbase to get the transaction back.  This doesn't seem to be the case after looking at the address 
it sent to,  1FLzbNekYywP7DeYwYjTKwktrHuzmpoCMj

Why would this happen?  How would I get this random address when I know I specifically copied it from my ready to activate XRP wallet?  Is this a lost cause?  Now afraid to invest in Ripple, seems shady.

Comment: Where did you get the 1FLzbNekYywP7DeYwYjTKwktrHuzmpoCMj address from? Who was going to convert BTC to XRP for you? Ask them why they didn't send you your XRP. (Also, as an employee of Ripple, I have to ask why you would think Ripple seems shady when you did business only with Coinbase and Toast. Ripple doesn't convert BTC to XRP. Ripple didn't give you a BTC address to send BTC to.)

Comment: Appreciated your response, obviously I'm new to this and upon my research to purchase XRP, none of this was made clear.  It makes sense now that it would need to be converted first.  Now that i have more information I will invest.  I guess the 'shady' part comes in the 20 xrp minimum.  I usually like to start in small amounts to make sure I'm doing the transactions properly.  Because of this minimum and fees this took a chunk of btc, and learned the hard way.  As an employee for ripple which conversion tool and wallet do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you must convert your BTC to XRP before transferring to them into an XRP wallet. You cannot send BTC to a non-bitcoin wallet.  Each cryptocurrency has their own address system/key pair that is compatible with their coin. As you know, Coinbase does not trade XRP so you would have had to transfer your BTC to another exchange that trades XRP or use shapeshift.io or changelly.com to convert BTC to XRP then transfer to your XRP wallet. I can’t explain how your BTC transferred to an unkown BTC address.  This sounds a little fishy that Coinbase would send your BTC to an address that you didn’t authorize so you should check with them. The blockchain shows that the address you listed received .00327327 on Jan 6 but subsequently was emptied of BTC the next day. You may be out of luck . Sorry.

Comment: If it was the wallet of some service converts BTC to XRP, it would make sense that they would empty the wallet after funds were sent to them.

Comment: @David Schwartz, Does Coinbase send crypto to an exchange service on behalf of customers before transferring into another currency wallet?

Answer (score 0):

To go from one currency trype to another you need to exchange them.  You can't store one type of currency in another currency's wallet. bitcoin wallets are for Bitcoin.  XRP wallets are for XRP.

If you sent Bitcoin to an XRP wallet you are screwed.  Maybe coinbase can help?

Answer (score 0):

You made a beginners mistake. You can't send XRP to BTC wallet. This is a common problem. You have to have XRP Wallet Address in order to send (deposit) or withdraw, this thing happens all the time apparently, people send wrong curencies to BTC wallets all the time. There are professionals that know how to retreive it but this is in some rare scenarios people that program on blockchain based projects would probably know. I've heard from one developer on twitter that he recovered some coins before but I can't guarantee anything.